# ¿Cómo evitar registros duplicados en tablas relacionadas en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

La tabla *Suscription* tiene una columna llamada *serviceId* cuyo valor repetido (2 veces) representa el ID de la tabla que estamos usando la función `SUM`... por lo tanto en la consulta me trae 2 veces el valor de `sum(p.amount)`...
¿Cómo configuro la consulta para que solo me utilice la función SUM una única vez...?
Intenté meter un `DISTINCT` dentro de un subselect para ver si de esta forma genero una condición que me impida traerme valores repetidos de una tabla relacionada, pero nada... No me funcionó.

```
select 'Vuelto' as 'srvType', SUM(p.amount) as 'totalAmount', cc.name as 'currency' 

from p2p p, p2p_response t, currency cc, company c, user u, subscription sub 


where sub.serviceid IN 

(SELECT distinct sub.serviceid 

FROM subscription sub 

where sub.companyid=1 and sub.serviceid=2)


and t.p2pid = p.p2pid 

AND u.userid = p.userid 

AND p.currencyid=cc.currencyid 

AND u.companyid = c.companyid 

AND sub.companyid = u.companyid 

AND sub.companyid = c.companyid 

AND c.companyid=1 

AND sub.statusid=3 

and STR_TO_DATE(p.trndate,'%d-%m-%Y') >= STR_TO_DATE('23-01-2023','%d-%m-%Y') 

AND STR_TO_DATE(p.trndate,'%d-%m-%Y') <= STR_TO_DATE('23-01-2023','%d-%m-%Y')

and (t.referenceNumber != 'null' and t.referenceNumber != '') HAVING SUM(p.amount) IS NOT NULL;
```

---

Me solucioné usando la siguiente query, sin embargo no me funciona cuando distintos *serviceID* se repiten...

```
select 'Vuelto' as 'srvType', SUM(p.amount) as 'totalAmount', cc.name as 'currency' from p2p p, p2p_response t, currency cc, company c, user u, subscription sub where sub.serviceid IN (SELECT distinct sub.serviceid=2 FROM subscription sub where sub.statusid=3) and t.p2pid = p.p2pid AND u.userid = p.userid AND p.currencyid=cc.currencyid AND u.companyid = c.companyid AND sub.companyid = u.companyid AND sub.companyid = c.companyid AND c.companyid=1 and STR_TO_DATE(p.trndate,'%d-%m-%Y') >= STR_TO_DATE('24-01-2023','%d-%m-%Y') 
AND STR_TO_DATE(p.trndate,'%d-%m-%Y') <= STR_TO_DATE('24-01-2023','%d-%m-%Y') and (t.referenceNumber != 'null' and t.referenceNumber != '') HAVING SUM(p.amount) IS NOT NULL

union select 'Pago con tarjeta' as 'srvType', SUM(cp.amount) as 'totalAmount', cc.name as 'currency' from card_payment cp, card_payment_response cpr, currency cc, company c, user u, subscription sub where sub.serviceid IN (SELECT distinct sub.serviceid=1 FROM subscription sub where sub.statusid=3) and cpr.idcardpayment = cp.idcardpayment and u.userid = cp.userid AND cp.currencyid=cc.currencyid AND u.companyid = c.companyid AND sub.companyid = u.companyid AND sub.companyid = c.companyid and c.companyid=1 and STR_TO_DATE(cpr.datetime,'%d-%m-%Y') >= STR_TO_DATE('24-01-2023','%d-%m-%Y') 
AND STR_TO_DATE(cpr.datetime,'%d-%m-%Y') <= STR_TO_DATE('24-01-2023','%d-%m-%Y') and (cpr.reference != 'null' and cpr.reference != '') HAVING SUM(cp.amount) IS NOT NULL 
            
union select 'Pago movil' as 'srvType', SUM(pm.amount) as 'totalAmount', cc.name as 'currency' from pago_movil pm, currency cc, company c, user u, subscription sub where sub.serviceid IN (SELECT distinct sub.serviceid=3 FROM subscription sub where sub.statusid=3) and u.userid = pm.userid and pm.currencyid=cc.currencyid and u.companyid = c.companyid AND sub.companyid = u.companyid AND sub.companyid = c.companyid and c.companyid=1 and sub.statusid=3 and STR_TO_DATE(pm.createdat,'%d-%m-%Y') >= STR_TO_DATE('24-01-2023','%d-%m-%Y') 
AND STR_TO_DATE(pm.createdat,'%d-%m-%Y') <= STR_TO_DATE('24-01-2023','%d-%m-%Y') and (pm.reference != 'null' and pm.reference != '') HAVING SUM(pm.amount) IS NOT NULL 
            
union select 'Transferencia' as 'srvType', SUM(tt.amount) as 'totalAmount', cc.name as 'currency' from transfer tt, currency cc, company c, user u, subscription sub where sub.serviceid IN (SELECT distinct sub.serviceid=3 FROM subscription sub where sub.statusid=3) and u.userid = tt.userid and tt.currencyid=cc.currencyid and u.companyid = c.companyid AND sub.companyid = u.companyid AND sub.companyid = c.companyid and c.companyid=1 and sub.statusid=3 and STR_TO_DATE(tt.createdat,'%d-%m-%Y') >= STR_TO_DATE('24-01-2023','%d-%m-%Y') 
AND STR_TO_DATE(tt.createdat,'%d-%m-%Y') <= STR_TO_DATE('24-01-2023','%d-%m-%Y') and (tt.reference != 'null' and tt.reference != '') HAVING SUM(tt.amount) IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: ya probaste con DISTINCTROW

Comment: Si, pero no funcionó.
Gracias.

Comment: Por favor, ya no vuelvas a insertar las etiquetas [phpmyadmin] y [mysql-workbench], porque no tienen relación con la pregunta. Tampoco [mysqli], ya que es una extensión de PHP para MySQL. _Lee la descripción de las etiquetas_, colocando el mouse sobre cada una de ellas.

Comment: @padaleiana Ok entendido.

Answer (score 0):

A ver, es complicado sin datos, pero las relaciones que pones de tablas están un poco difusas, personalmente, me gusta especificar cada una de ellas:

```
SELECT 'Vuelto' AS 'srvType', SUM(DISTINCT p.amount) AS 'totalAmount', cc.name AS 'currency' 
FROM p2p AS p
INNER JOIN p2p_response AS t ON t.p2pid = p.p2pid 
INNER JOIN currency AS cc ON p.currencyid=cc.currencyid 
-- INNER JOIN company AS c ON c=1
INNER JOIN user AS u ON u.userid = p.userid 
INNER JOIN subscription AS sub ON sub.companyid = u.companyid    
WHERE true
  AND sub.statusid=3 
  AND STR_TO_DATE(p.trndate,'%d-%m-%Y') >= STR_TO_DATE('23-01-2023','%d-%m-%Y') 
  AND STR_TO_DATE(p.trndate,'%d-%m-%Y') <= STR_TO_DATE('23-01-2023','%d-%m-%Y')
  -- and (t.referenceNumber != 'null' and t.referenceNumber != '')    
  AND (t.referenceNumber IS NOT NULL and t.referenceNumber != '')  -- más sencillo -> and COALESCE(t.referenceNumber,'') != '') 
  AND sub.companyid=1 
  AND sub.serviceid=2
 HAVING SUM(p.amount) IS NOT NULL
```

He quitado la tabla company porque aquí no se usa para nada.

También quité el `where sub.serviceid IN` porque es un poco limitante y como esa tabla ya está relacionada es redundante.

También quité el `t.referenceNumber != 'null'` porque a menos que guarde el literal `'null'` no va a funcionar.

Para analizar lo que te está pasando puedes sacar el resultado sin el `sum()` a ver si estas conforme con las columnas que salen, a partir de ahí añade un comentario según los datos que salgan:

```
SELECT 'Vuelto' AS 'srvType', p.amount AS 'amount', cc.name AS 'currency'     FROM p2p AS p
INNER JOIN p2p_response AS t ON t.p2pid = p.p2pid 
INNER JOIN currency AS cc ON p.currencyid=cc.currencyid 
INNER JOIN user AS u ON u.userid = p.userid 
INNER JOIN subscription AS sub ON sub.companyid = u.companyid    
WHERE true
  AND sub.statusid=3 
  AND STR_TO_DATE(p.trndate,'%d-%m-%Y') >= STR_TO_DATE('23-01-2023','%d-%m-%Y') 
  AND STR_TO_DATE(p.trndate,'%d-%m-%Y') <= STR_TO_DATE('23-01-2023','%d-%m-%Y')
  AND (t.referenceNumber IS NOT NULL ANDt.referenceNumber != '')  
  AND sub.companyid=1 
  AND sub.serviceid=2
 HAVING SUM(p.amount) IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo que hiciste es justo lo que estaba buscando, ya lo probé... es impresionante que lo hayas logrado sin necesidad de correr nuestra base de datos... Sin embargo una consulta mas... solo si puedes. 
¿Cómo hago para que ese mismo query que hiciste, me traiga únicamente 'Vuelto' AS 'srvType' cuando no existan registros y si sub.statusid=3 ?

Comment: statusid=1 =solicitado
statusid=2 = leido
statuisid=3 = APROBADO

Me están pidiendo que cuando una consulta no traiga registros y el statusid sea diferente de 3 entonces... ocurra lo que hiciste, es decir no traiga nada... pero si el statusid=3 entonces que al menos salga 'Vuelto' AS 'srvType' como único registro de la consulta. :(

Comment: Me alegro que te sirviera, para las condicionales revisa la [documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/if.html)  y si tienes algún problema haz una nueva pregunta, ya sabes, con un [example]  ;)